# Randomly pick photo from User model ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

The schema for my ruby on rails app is below. I am currently filling my home page and want to randomly pick photo(s) from a random existing user to feature on the home page.

I have tried a lot of things in my home controller and cant seem to get it right...

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @featured = User.find(:all, :limit => 4, :order => 'RANDOM()')
    @users = User.find(:all)
    user_count = User.count()
    offset = rand(0..(user_count-1))
    @my_user = User.find(:all, :limit => 1, :offset => offset )
  end
end
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
@photo = User.find(:order => 'RANDOM()').photo

@user = User.find(:all, :limit => 1, :order => 'RANDOM()')
@photo = Photo.find(@user)
```

I get errors like such: Couldn't find Photo with id=6

### How would I go about  this without pointing to a nil location/non-existent photo...?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130513143229) do

  create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "image"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with an `offset` clause.

First, get the total number of users you have.

`user_count = User.count()`

Then get a random number between 0 and this number - 1.

`offset = rand(0..(user_count - 1))`

Then select with the offset to get a random user

`my_user = User.find(:all, :limit => 1, :offset => offset)`

To get a random subset of pictures from your random user use the same procedure, with a couple caveats.  Change the `:limit` to how many pictures you want, make sure your random offset is `number_of_pictures - picture_limit`, and make sure when you count your pictures, you are counting only the subset you want to select from (`Photo.count(:user_id => my_user.id)`).  This isn't completely random, because the picture subset you get will be in whatever order the database wants to put it in, at least the subset will start at a random place so the set should usually be different.

Comment: I must be missing something... I've updated the controller as you've stated and to test it, i went and tried set up a link to 'my_user' in home/index.html.erb and i get: undefined local variable or method `my_user' i sort of get what you mean with photos... however i get errors when implementing that too.

Comment: my_user should be @my_user if you want to use it in a view

Comment: @DizzyChamp - DGM is right, to access these variables in the view they need to be instance variables, ie, with the `@`.  What errors are you getting implementing the photos?

Comment: <%=link_to @my_user.id, @my_user %> Im using this in the index apart of the home controller scope and im getting 'undefined method `id' for... so im guessing im doing something but ive done exactly as youve stated above. Ive updated my post to show what ive done so far.

Comment: Funnily enough, when I look on the server error page it says @my_user has been populated with a randomly selected user's details... its unusual that when i call for an id or name... it says no method..

Comment: undefined method 'id' for...what exactly? is it nil or an unexpected class? Try `raise @my_user.inspect` in your controller so you can see what class @my_user is and whether it's supposed to respond to `id`.

Comment: I've found out my issue. I've been using User.find(:all....) that creates an array of user objects. I was then calling @ my_user.id or @ my_user.name which is accessing the array and not a user within that array...

Answer (score 0):

Ok with the help of Scott.. ive come to a solution that works perfectly...

One issue was calling the specific photo from views/index for home.

The correct call to view an image at the home page was as follows:

```
<%=link_to @my_user[0].name, @my_user[0] %>
<%= image_tag @fphoto[0].image_url(:thumb) if @fphoto[0].image? %>
```

And there i have a random image...

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @featured = User.find(:all, :limit => 4, :order => 'RANDOM()')
    @users = User.find(:all)
    user_count = User.count()
    offset = rand(0..(user_count-1))
    @my_user = User.find(:all, :limit => 1, :offset => offset )
    picture_count = Photo.count(params[:user_id => @my_user[0].id])
    poffset = rand(0..(picture_count - 1))
    @fphoto = Photo.find(:all, :limit => 1, :offset => poffset )

  end
end
```